# How to check if chart was already created

Tags: excel, vba

I'm adding a chart via vba with the following commands:

```
Dim CsvVisualization As ChartObject
Set ChartSizePosition = Range("B8:I25")
Set CsvVisualization = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Übersicht").ChartObjects.Add(ChartSizePosition.Left, ChartSizePosition.Top, ChartSizePosition.Width, ChartSizePosition.Height)
CsvVisualization.Name = "MeasurementVisualization"
With CsvVisualization.Chart
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
...
```

How could I proofe if this chart was already created when the excel file is reopened? I tried something like:

```
If CsvVisualization Is Nothing Then
```

But CsvVisualization won't hold it's value when the file is closed and opened again.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look at all the charts in the workbook to see if a chart with that name already exists when the sheet opens with:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim testChart As ChartObject

    For Each testChart In ThisWorkbook.Charts
        If testChart.Name = "MeasurementVisualization" Then
            'Chart exists, so do something or not or whatever or what have you
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @FreeMan I like that you are just looking at charts in the tab that OP cares about. I'm just carelessly looking at all of them with this.

Comment: I basically copied that code from a project I'm currently working on, then stuck his chart creation bits in there...

Answer (score 6):

```
Dim CsvVisualization As ChartObject
Dim MyChartName as string
Dim CreateChart as Boolean

MyChartName = "MeasurementVisualization"
CreateChart = True

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Übersicht").ChartObjects.Count = 0 Then
  For Each CsvVisualization in ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Übersicht").ChartObjects
    If CsvVisualization.name = MyChartName then
      CreateChart = False
    End If
  Next
End if

If CreateChart then
  Set ChartSizePosition = Range("B8:I25")
  Set CsvVisualization = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Übersicht").ChartObjects.Add(ChartSizePosition.Left, ChartSizePosition.Top, ChartSizePosition.Width, ChartSizePosition.Height)
CsvVisualization.Name = "MeasurementVisualization"
  With CsvVisualization.Chart
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try if you would get an error by referencing the object

```
On Error Resume Next
Set CurrentChart = thisworkbook.sheets("Übersicht").ChartObjects("MeasurementVisualization")
On Error GoTo 0

If IsEmpty(CurrentChart) Then
MsgBox "Not found"
Else
CurrentChart.Activate
End If
```

you can replace my codes inside the If with creating the chart....